# Inacessible Host on Amplify Init

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I'm initializing empty (initial files created by npx create-next-app) React/NextJs application with amplify init, but receiving the following error:

```
Inaccessible host: amplify.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' at port 443'. This service may not be available in the `us-west-2' region.
```

Failed Attempts:

- Another region (sp-east-1)
- Create another amplify user

Windows Test-NetConnection executed with success on amplify.us-west-2.amazonaws.com at port 443. Not using proxy, network connection working.

**Reproduction steps**

1. Run amplify configure to save profile information about amplify user
2. Create a NextJs project with npx create-next-app
3. Run amplify init
4. Accept all default configurations
5. Select AWS Proflie authentication method (tried with access key as well)
6. Use different profiles configured, with different regions

Any suggestions?